# One null image url prevents other things from getting displayed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-widget, bitmap

I am able to get the data from the sqlite database. However, when my image url is null, it prevents my other things from getting displayed.

```
try{
                name.setText(nameString);
                school.setText(schoolString);
                psupervisor.setText(info.getPsupervisor());
                pdate.setText(info.getPdate());
                a.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick1()));
                b.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick2()));
                c.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick3()));
                pcomment1.setText(info.getPcomment1());
                psignature1.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature1()));
                pcomment2.setText(info.getPcomment2());
                psignature2.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature2()));
                pdate2.setText(info.getPdate2());
                d.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick4()));
                e.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick5()));
                f.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick6()));
                pcomment3.setText(info.getPcomment3());
                psignature3.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature3()));
                pcomment4.setText(info.getPcomment4());
                psignature4.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature4()));
                Log.d("PREPOST: ", log2);
                db.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}

        }
```

For example if psignature2 is null, the items from pdate2 to pcomment4 would not get displayed. *Didn't crash due to the try-catch therefore I discovered the cause of error late*

My method for adjustment of bitmap resolution:

```
public Bitmap resizeSignatureBitmap(String imagePath){

     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
            is = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
    try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
            is = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    // here w and h are the desired width and height
    options.inSampleSize = Math.max(options.outWidth/w, options.outHeight/h);
    // bitmap is the resized bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
    is=null;
     return bitmap;
 }
```

Therefore, can anyone suggest any methods that I can do so that even if there is a null image url, it would not prevent the display of other image? Thanks!

Comment: You have one big Try-Catch, if somethings goes wrong the code stops running, try setting images in a separated try-catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `resizeSignatureBitmap` you can apply a check at the end to check weather the `bitmap` to be returned is `null` or not. In case its `null` you can return some default bitmap.

Or you can simply set images in separate `try catch blocks`.

Comment: One more option would be to apply a null check before setting the images. i.e. just check weather the bitmap to be applied is null or not. If its not null, then set it to ImageView otherwise dont set it.